# Jmeter with maven and using external groovy scripts issues with groovy imports

Tags: maven, groovy, jmeter, gson

I'd like to execute jmeter tests from maven using groovy scripts, but I got the error below. For setting up jmeter and maven I did what is described [here](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin/).

Shall I package my groovy functions and entities into a jar and copy into jmeter's lib directory and only put those groovy scripts next to the jmx file which contains the sampler code?

```
2019-06-22 17:40:17,714 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2019-06-22 17:40:17,714 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
2019-06-22 17:40:17,744 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script CreateUsers, message: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script4.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class com.google.gson.Gson
 @ line 4, column 1.
   import com.google.gson.Gson;
   ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

- I need to package into jars my libraries I'd like to use in testing and put them into `jmeter/lib` directory
- I have to align Sampler scripts path, so jmeter can work with them

The solution for the first is the following from [jmeter-maven-plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-Excluding-libraries-to-from-the-classpath) doc:

```
<project>
    [...]
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>USE LAST VERSION</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jmeter</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <testPlanLibraries>
                             <artifact>org.apache.activemq:activemq-spring:5.15.2</artifact>
                 <artifact>org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:5.15.2</artifact>
                 <artifact>org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.15.2</artifact>
                </testPlanLibraries>
                        <excludedArtifacts>
                             <exclusion>com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools</exclusion>
                             <exclusion>com.sun.jmx:jmxri</exclusion>
            </excludedArtifacts>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    [...]
</project>
```

The solution for the second is that I need to copy Sampler scripts next to jmx file. Maven can do this easily using [maven-resource-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You  need to add to your pom.xml [Gson dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google/gson/2.1.0)

> ```
> <dependency>
> <groupId>com.google</groupId>
> <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
> <version>2.1.0</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

Comment: It doesn't help, see my answer below.