# How to define constants which can be used in multiple script files in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I'm writing tests in JMeter environment. Leveraging on groovy and writing re-usable code resulted that we will have multiple script files and a single one where the constants are defined. And here is my question, how is possible to access to constants defined in a file from the script files?

Why it is important for me? There are decision points in the logic of the test cases, and there is some data placed in Jmeter.props global variable where the key is string. I'd like to store these keys in a constant class to avoid typos in the future.

I'd like to achieve something similar:

Groovy file 1

```
class Constants {
    public final static String PREFIX = 'prefix'
}
```

Groovy file 2

```
void methodName() {

    printlin("===> " + Constants.PREFIX)
}

methodName()
===> prefix
```

First try was something similar:

Groovy file 1

```
class Constants {
    public final static String PREFIX = "prefix"
}
```

Groovy file 2

```
void methodName() {

    printlin("===> " + Constants.PREFIX)
}

methodName()
```

which resulted in an error message where the compiler was looking for Constants property of methodName.ScriptWhatever class
This case the files were in the same package.

The second try was dealing with @Fields, but I couldn't figure out how is possible to distribute the values of the constants in the way you have define them only a single place.

The funny was that, I included one of these constants like the following and it worked...

```
void methodName() {

    printLn("===> " + Inspector.CLASS_CLASS_IDX)
}

methodName()
```

If I remember correctly, in java you can solve this problem like this:

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String PREFIX = "prefix";
}

public class AnotherClass {
    public void doIt() { System.out.println(Constants.PREFIX); }
}
```

And the result is "prefix"
(Sorry, my java knowledge is pretty rusty still)

Comment: The first variant should work if file named Constants.groovy and located in classpath

Comment: The class is in the same directory as the script it uses. I'll double check this classpath thing, thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

All your `constant` classes (scripts) must be visible, i.e. be present in class-path of execution environments for all other scripts. Otherwise you would be getting `NoSuch*Exception`s.

I'm not an expert on groovy class-free wild scripting, but off the hip your can try packaging your constant class/-es into a `.jar` file and use `@Grab` annotation in other scripts to reference the former.

Comment: Will check these too. Until then I'll keep my script complexity on bare minimum to be able to progress.

Answer (score 0):

Following [@dagett33](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276664/daggett) advice I added the generated jar to jmeter's `lib` directory as I described in my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56717085/jmeter-with-maven-and-using-external-groovy-scripts-issues-with-groovy-imports) and it's working fine.